# Algorithm related to partitions

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

I hope this is not a foolish question...

Define $T(n,k)$ = number of partitions of $n$ in which the greatest part is $k$, $1 \le k \le n$. The triangle for $n$ = {1,..,10} looks like:

1: [1]

2: [1, 1]

3: [1, 1, 1]

4: [1, 2, 1, 1]

5: [1, 2, 2, 1, 1]

6: [1, 3, 3, 2, 1, 1]

7: [1, 3, 4, 3, 2, 1, 1]

8: [1, 4, 5, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1]

9: [1, 4, 7, 6, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1]

10: [1, 5, 8, 9, 7, 5, 3, 2, 1, 1]

( See oeis.org/A008284)

I have coded an algorithm that builds the triangle above in ascending order.  I have searched for any similar algorithm without success.  Everything I find typically uses recursion to build this triangle in descending order.  I have looked at Jerome Kelleher's ruleAsc algorithm which enumerates all partitions of $n$ in ascending order, but my algorithm does not require such enumeration.  Is anyone aware of another algorithm that can build this triangle in ascending order?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand, but it sounds interesting.

Comment: Ok now maybe I understand. I am curious if one technique I have used for ncr and factorial could work.

Comment: @mathreadler As a benchmark, on a duel-core 3GHz PC using python, I can compute the complete triangle from 1 to 10,000 in ~3 minutes. Don't know how fast Mathematica can do this. Maybe someone out there can time Mathematica? It's almost certain to be faster. – jnthn 10 mins ago   delete

Comment: I also don't know about many different algorithms for calculating this particular thing, but I think I have one method that may work, if I can find my old approach to a similar problem maybe I can try it on this one.

Comment: Just to be clear, Mathematica will be faster.

Comment: I haven't even implemented it yet, how would you know?

Comment: Sorry, not yours.  I was referring to my own benchmark  comment.

Comment: Ah okay, yes well Mathematica probably has lots of engineers and mathematicians building optimized routines for their software. Would probably take some effort to beat.

Comment: What do you mean by ascending and descending order in this context?

Comment: @PeterTaylor I construct the triangle in ascending order from 1 to n. Most algorithms I find start with n and recurrsively break the number down until 1 is reached. In response to my Mathematica query I was informed that using the second formula found in A008284, and running a half-day test, it would take an estimated three days to cumpute A008284(10,000). Not sure if a different formula would be faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The definition of *algorithm* is not completely precise, so there is sometimes ambiguity as to whether two computer programs (or other processes) are implementing the same algorithm or related but distinct algorithms. For this reason, I'm think your question is rather hard to pin down and I'm not sure that a precise answer can be given. I will attempt to explain some general background, hoping to pitch it at the right level that it answers the question behind the question and gives you the insight you want.

Every recursive function can be written as an iterative loop, and every iterative loop can be written as a recursive function. (If you've studied extremely simple models of computation, this is evident from the equivalence of the Turing machine and the lambda calculus). The most general transformation from a recursive function to an iterative loop is to use a stack data structure to essentially simulate the call stack. However, there is another style of transformation from recursive function to iterative loop called *dynamic programming*. The canonical illustration is with the Fibonacci numbers. We start with a recursive definition:

```
fib(n) {
    if (n == 0) return 0;
    if (n == 1) return 1;
    return fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
}
```

This runs extremely slowly, because if we call `fib(1000)` it calls `fib(999)` (which calls `fib(998)`, ...) and then `fib(998)`. The total number of calls is exponential in `n`.

An intermediate step is to *memoise* the function, or cache its results.

```
fibcache = { 0 => 0 , 1 => 1 };

fib(n) {
    if (n in fibcache) return fibcache[n];

    result = fib(n - 1) + fib(n - 2);
    fibcache[n] = result;
    return result;
}
```

This now only performs each sum once, because thereafter it is cached. It gives an exponential speedup, to time linear in `n`. The *dynamic programming* step is to invert the call sequence and build the cache from the bottom up.

```
fib(n) {
    fibcache = { 0 => 0 , 1 => 1 };
    i = 2;
    while (i <= n) {
        fibcache[i] = fibcache[i - 1] + fibcache[i - 2];
    }
    return fibcache[n];
}
```

Obviously with the Fibonacci numbers you can go further: ditch the cache and just keep the previous two values; or use a matrix power to get a further exponential speed-up. But the dynamic programming step is the point of this particular exposition.

What you appear to be describing is precisely a dynamic programming iterative formulation of the recursive function

```
T(n, k) {
    if (k < 1 or k > n) return 0;
    if (k == 1 or k == n) return 1;
    return T(n - 1, k - 1) + T(n - k, k)
}
```

If your question is whether anyone has previously implemented such, the answer is yes. For example, I could point you at [an implementation I wrote](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/32821/194) a bit over three years ago in a [language](http://www.golfscript.com/golfscript/) which you've almost certainly not heard of and probably shouldn't bother learning. But the recurrence has been known for a long time (it's presented as folklore in [Partitions - A Survey](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/jres/74B/jresv74Bn1p1_A1b.pdf), Hansraj Gupta, Journal of Research of the National Bureau of Standards - B. Mathematical Sciences, Vol. 74B, No.1, January-March 1970; see section 4), and it was probably implemented by dynamic programming on paper before computers even existed. I wouldn't bet against Euler having already derived and implemented it, again in "descending order".

Comment: That was the answer I was looking for...and now see it was a foolish question.

Comment: @jnthn, I think (and hope) the majority of intelligent people would see no shame in asking foolish questions from time to time: asking questions to which the answer seems obvious in hindsight is to be expected when you're thinking about subjects near the edge of your current knowledge, and the days when one person could know "everything" are long behind us. And then sometimes a question which seems foolish turns out to have unexpected depths and leads into new areas of original research.

Comment: @jnthn, with respect to your question via OEIS: I can have a look, but I wonder whether you might be better served by posting on a suitable stack so that more people can look at it.

Comment: I'll post a new question and put a link here.